# How to solve Null response on receive data from server with JSON Swift and PHP

Tags: php, json, server, ios9

I'm trying to send and receive data from an app and server using Swift, JSON and PHP but I receive all null values. 
the response of server is:

```
 porte
 <null>
 venditore
 <null>
 cilindrata
 <null>
 ordine
 <null>
 catalizzatore
 <null>
 IVA
 <null>
 percentualeammortamento
 <null>
 cognome
 <null>
 garanzia
 <null>
 targa
 <null>
 alimentazione
 <null>
 marca
 <null>
 KM
 <null>
 sinistri
 <null>
 modello
 <null>
 telaio
 <null>
 indirizzo
 <null>
 data
 <null>
 colore
 <null>
 dossier
 <null>
```

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
class SaveViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {



var data_save:String! ="SomeString"
var venditore_save:String! ="SomeString"
var ordine_save:String! ="SomeString"
var dossier_save:String! ="SomeString"
var marca_save:String! ="SomeString"
var modello_save:String! ="SomeString"
var cilindrata_save:String! ="SomeString"
var targa_save:String! ="SomeString"
var telaio_save:String! ="SomeString"
var alimentazione_save:String! ="SomeString"
var catalizzatore_save:String! ="SomeString"
var porte_save:String! ="SomeString"
var colore_save:String! ="SomeString"
var km_save:String! ="SomeString"
var garanzia_save:String! ="SomeString"
var incidenti_save:String! ="SomeString"
var cognome_save:String! ="SomeString"
var indirizzo_save:String! ="SomeString"
var iva_save:Bool! ="SomeString"
 var percentualeammortamento_save:String! ="SomeString"

 @IBAction func btnSignUp_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
let parameters = ["data":data_save, "venditore":venditore_save, "dossier":dossier_save,"ordine":ordine_save, "cognome":cognome_save,"indirizzo":indirizzo_save, "marca":marca_save, "modello":modello_save, "targa":targa_save, "telaio":telaio_save, "cilindrata":cilindrata_save, "alimentazione":alimentazione_save, "catalizzatore":catalizzatore_save, "KM":km_save, "porte":porte_save, "colore":colore_save, "sinistri":incidenti_save, "garanzia":garanzia_save, "IVA": String(iva_save), "percentualeammortamento":percentualeammortamento_save] as Dictionary<String, String>


    let url = NSURL(string: "myurl") //change the url



    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()



    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    let err: NSError?


    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options:[])


    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")





    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }



        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? NSDictionary {
                let success = json["success"] as? Int                                  

                print("Success: \(success)")
            } else {
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    // No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)                                                          

            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}





  @IBAction  func btnLoadUser_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {

let url = NSURL(string: "myurl")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)



let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if data == nil {
        print("request failed \(error)")
        return
    }



        do{

            let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                for (key, value) in json {


                    let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject([key, value], options:[])



                    print(key)

                    print(value)}
}catch {
            print("bom bom bom error")
        }

    }
    task.resume() } }
```

Here's the php code:

```
   <?php 
$ricambio = array();
$ricambio['data'] = $_POST['data'];
$ricambio['venditore'] = $_POST['venditore'];
$ricambio['dossier'] = $_POST['dossier'];
$ricambio['ordine'] = $_POST['ordine'];
$ricambio['cognome'] = $_POST['cognome'];
$ricambio['indirizzo'] = $_POST['indirizzo'];
$ricambio['marca'] = $_POST['marca'];
$ricambio['modello'] = $_POST['modello'];
$ricambio['targa'] = $_POST['targa'];
$ricambio['telaio'] = $_POST['telaio'];
$ricambio['cilindrata'] = $_POST['cilindrata'];
$ricambio['alimentazione'] = $_POST['alimentazione'];
$ricambio['catalizzatore'] = $_POST['catalizzatore'];
$ricambio['KM'] = $_POST['KM'];
$ricambio['porte'] = $_POST['porte'];
$ricambio['colore'] = $_POST['colore'];
$ricambio['sinistri'] = $_POST['sinistri'];
$ricambio['garanzia'] = $_POST['garanzia'];
$ricambio['IVA'] = $_POST['IVA'];
$ricambio['percentualeammortamento'] = $_POST['percentualeammortamento'];

echo json_encode($ricambio);


?>
```

Any solutions? Maybe the problem is the options:[] in

```
 try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(parameters, options:[]
```

Answer (score 0):

When POSTing a json body to PHP it won't automatically decode the json string into the $_POST superglobal.

Try something like

```
$jsonBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($jsonBody);

var_dump($decoded);
```

Comment: I don't save in a file, the problem is that the PHP don't receive the value

Comment: Have you tried the code? 'php://input' isn't a normal file, it is the input stream

Comment: If you copy and paste my code example into your PHP file, what response do you get?

Comment: I get the same result, all values are Null